# expression in split component in SSIS giving error

Tags: ssis

I am trying to implement conditional split component in my SSIS package. I need to split the records based on the year. I need to extract data for the last 5 years and need to split it before i dump it to the destination

periodenddate is datetime field. I need to extract the year part from that field and compare it against the actual year as mentioned in the expression. I am getting an error for invalid expression. Could somebody tell me where am i going wrong

The expression i am using is for eg

```
periodEndDate == YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Please find the error attached

[image]

Second error

[image]

Third error

[image]

Comment: `periodenddate` is all lower case, not camel case!

Comment: I tried putting lowercase still getting error. Please see the screenshot titles second error. Also tried single equals operator

Comment: It's hard to answer a question when you tried three different things, got three different errors, but you only show the code for one attempt.   The reason for the error in the code you are showing is because of the lower case, since SSIS is case sensitive.   Fix that, show the code you are using now and the error you get from it, and it might be possible to help you further.

Comment: The expression is in the error message, @TabAlleman, although I agree that having it separately would make the question easier to read.

Comment: Based on your other question.... you know this is not doing anything in parallel right? You're still just reading from the table in one go. If you had five data flows and your table was _partitioned_ then there's a chance things might go in parallel. But again you're posing an overcomplicated answer to a problem that doesn't yet exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the year number from one year ago, you need to use:

```
YEAR([periodenddate]) = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1
YEAR([periodenddate]) = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 2
etc.
```

Having the "-1" inside the parentheses for the Year() function will give you the wrong answer at the very least.

Note that you got different errors with each version of your code:

- The first image shows a failure to find a field due to SSIS being case sensitive
- The second image shows a failure due to comparing a datetimestamp to an integer
- The third image shows an error with the expression "GETDATE() - 1", which is on a different conditional expression component than the first two images.